# Screen frozen, music missing

Tags: ipod-classic

My friend and I switched ipods to experience each other's music. His is and ipod classic while mine was a touch.

When the battery started to run low I hooked it up to my computer. I have my itunes set to manually manage music but itunes immediately popped up when my computer recognized the ipod. It was giving me this message that was like it knew it wasn't my ipod and it was telling me I need to restore the ipod. Of course I freaked out and safely disconnected the ipod as soon as possible.

After that the ipod was stuck on the "ok to disconnect" screen. I wasn't sure what to do so I let it die. I instead hooked it up to my car stereo in order to charge it. The stereo wouldn't read any music on the ipod when it was finally charged and it was still stuck on the same screen as before.

Did I lose all of his music? Is there anything I can do to get it back to normal without having to give his ipod back?

Please help, I am desperate and not used to classics.

Answer (score 2):

Performing a hard reset may restore your friend's iPod to working order - doing it should *not* affect the music loaded onto the iPod. Apple provides instructions for doing this [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1320). From the relevant section:

> 1. Toggle the Hold switch on and off. (Slide it to Hold, then turn it off again.)
> 2. Press and hold the Menu and Center (Select) buttons simultaneously until the Apple logo appears, about 6 to 8 seconds. You may need to
>      repeat this step.
>
> Tip: If you are having difficulty resetting your iPod, set it on a
>   flat surface. Make sure the finger pressing the Select button is not
>   touching any part of the click wheel. Also make sure that you are
>   pressing the Menu button toward the outside of the click wheel, and
>   not near the center.
>
> If the above steps did not work, try connecting iPod to a power
>   adapter and plug the power adapter into an electrical outlet, or
>   connect iPod to your computer. Make sure the computer is turned on and
>   isn't set to go to sleep. Try resetting the iPod while it is connected
>   to power.